# Ansible: How to use inventory variables in ad-hoc commands

Tags: ansible

I want to run an ad-hoc command over a host file, in the host file I have defined a variable for each host, How can I use that variable while executing an ad-hoc command.

For example:

```
ansible -i /home/bob/hosts_file -m shell -a "$VAR/project run"
```

I have defined the `$VAR` for each host in "hosts_file", the $VAR is different for every host in the inventory file. How can I use that variable in my ad-hoc command replacing for each host when executing.

Answer (score 5):

With Ansible ad-hoc commands `ansible` can make use of all the same variables regardless.

#### Examples

*#1. group_names*

```
$ ansible -i inventory/lab -m debug -a "var=group_names" all | head -10
es-master-01.mydom.local | SUCCESS => {
    "group_names": [
        "elasticsearch",
        "engineering",
        "lab",
        "lab-es-master"
    ]
}
```

Here I'm querying the servers in an inventory to find out what groups the server is assigned to in the inventory file. This variable `group_names` shows this from my inventory file.

*#2. inventory_hostnames*

Here's another example where I'm using the variable `inventory_hostnames` and accessing it using Jinja notation:

```
$ ansible -i inventory/nyc1 -l ocp-app* all -c local -m shell -a "echo {{ inventory_hostname }}"
ocp-app-01e.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01e.nyc1.dom.us

ocp-app-01c.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01c.nyc1.dom.us

ocp-app-01d.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01d.nyc1.dom.us

ocp-app-01a.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01a.nyc1.dom.us

ocp-app-01b.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01b.nyc1.dom.us

ocp-app-01f.nyc1.dom.us | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ocp-app-01f.nyc1.dom.us
```

Answer (score 4):

Host variables are available to ansible, even while running an ad-hoc command. You insert them as you would through a playbook, using a jinja template.

```
ansible all -i /home/bob/hosts_file -m shell -a "{{var}}/project run"
```